# SSL Certificate Error - Selenium Web Driver and Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate

While running my Test scripts, the SSL certificate error page show. Even after confirming the security exception manually, the certificate error page reloads. I tried handling this via code by by creating a custom profile in Firefox to accept untrusted SSL certs, but it didn't work.

```
   ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();

   FirefoxProfile myProfile = allProfiles.getProfile("QA");

   myProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

   myProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);

   driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
```

P.S The certificate error page doesn't pop-up when i ran the test on Windows machine; but unable to proceed on MAC OS.

Comment: i have asked the same question here let me know if you able to fix
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132331/untrusted-ssl-certificates-in-firefox-using-webdriver-and-c-sharp